# implement function for hiding buttons for guest users Yii2

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

First i want to say that i know there is many post about jQuery and Yii2 around the network but still can't make it clear for me! My question is pretty simple for you i think. When a user is with User role permission he shouldn't be able to update or delete others posts. And so if the user is this kind of guy i want to make both anchors ('Edit' and 'Delete') with opacity 0.5.

This is my view part:

```
<?php $form = \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::begin([
                                'method' => 'post'
                            ]);
                            ?>
                                <div class="col-md-8 text-left">
                                    <?= Html::a('Edit', ['update', 'id' => $model->post_id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']); ?>
                                    <?=
                                        Html::a('Delete', ['delete', 'id' => $model->post_id],
                                                          ['data-method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger']);
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
                                    <?= Html::a('Back', 'index', ['class' => 'btn btn-warning']); ?>
                                </div>

                            <?php \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

I have added my file to AppAsset.php(test.js):

`public $js = [
    'js/slide-show.js',
    'js/test.js'
];`

I know how to make my fucntion but do not know how to implement it. Think i should do it with if statement (`if(user->isGuest){ execute function and make anchros with opacity 0.5 }`). Can you guys teach me the right way? Will be thankful for every advice! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign a disable option  so the button is displayed  but disabled

```
if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
   echo Html::a('Edit', ['update', 'id' => $model->post_id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary',
          'disabled' => 'disabled']); 
    echo Html::a('Delete', ['delete', 'id' => $model->post_id],
               ['data-method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
                'disabled' => 'disabled']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll do it like this! Didn't know about this option! But soon or later i'll have to work with javascript also and that's i curious how can i make it with it :)

Comment: @TomaTomov  you can  do the same with jqery  or javascript DOM and tag manage function....  disable is an html tag attribute ..  so you can set or remove using javascript